# Restore Open master Key Encryption to Test Environment

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Environment: Win 2012 and SQL 2014 Standard edition.

Issue: I am doing a daily restore of the production database into our test server. The production database has a encryption key. The restore to the test server is a SQL Job that runs nightly.

Items Tried:  I have tried to include a step in the sql job to decrypt the key in the test environment: open master key decryption by password = ''.  I have tried using EXEC, sp_executesql and embedding the commands in a stored procedure.  The only thing that really works of when I open up management studio and run the command manually.

Results From the Job: The job runs successfully but does nothing. I adding logging and there is nothing indicating any errors. All the log say is Begin Executing.

Question: Does anybody know how I can embed the open master key decryption by password = '' step into the sql job where the command with work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue that you have is that you're successfully opening the master key within that session, but other sessions don't see that. You subsequently need to re-encrypt the database master key with the test server's service master key. Luckily, once you've opened the key with the password (as you already have), it's as easy as:

```
alter master key add encryption by service master key;
```

Also, you shouldn't need to do anything fancy in your `open master key…` statement. That is, no need to wrap it in `sp_executesql` or any of that.